# Do search engines see CSS generated content?

Tags: css, seo, pseudo-element

I'd like to know whether I can use css generated content on words or phrases that I'd like the search engines to index. A read that screen readers are a mixed bag if they interpret css generated content, but I haven't seen anything on search engines

Comment: What "content" is generated by CSS? I know is is limited :before/:after content (text) support, but ..

Comment: No definitive data that I know of. I would file this as similar to JavaScript and *assume* they don't. So if it is important content then I wouldn't generate it with CSS. Then again, CSS isn't good at generating content so this really shouldn't be a big issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no evidence of search engines using CSS generated content, and on general grounds, it is unlikely they use or will use it. It is not impossible, however. A search engine could have a full rendering engine that inspects all the textual content, including generated content. But there is little reason to think that they will.

For one thing, it would be considerable added complexity to the search engine software. For another, it would not pay off, since most sites do not use generated content or use it to add just some punctuation characters or other content that is rather irrelevant to searching.

So if you want search engines to index something, put it into the normal content.